# Microsoft Graph API- list all users with OneDrive license

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I want to list all users that have OneDrive license.
I an using this URL but doesn't work.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 4b585984-651b-448a-9e53-3b10f069cf7f or x/skuId eq c7df2760-2c81-4ef7-b578-5b5392b571df)
```

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately complex query on property assignedLicenses is not supported. If you do so, the API will throw the error "Complex query on property assignedLicenses is not supported". Being said that i can see it works for simple filter, like, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 4b585984-651b-448a-9e53-3b10f069cf7f)"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately complex query (Whatever you're trying to do above) on property assignedLicenses is not supported. If you do so, the API will throw the error:

> Complex query on property assignedLicenses is not supported

Being said that I can see it works for simple filter, like,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 4b585984-651b-448a-9e53-3b10f069cf7f)
```

Comment: Yes this query works but I wanted to retreive with a single call all users who have Onedrive.

Comment: As i updated you earlier if you use simple filter, it works; unfortunately not the complex ones.